# Idiomatic GPIO control in Linux 4.8+

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, gpio

The userspace interface to GPIOs was [changed](https://embeddedbits.org/new-linux-kernel-gpio-user-space-interface/) in Linux 4.8, deprecating the old sysfs interface in favor of a character device.  I am struggling to see how I can wrangle this new model into something that makes sense for my use case.

I have a peripheral device that I control from my ARM CPU using GPIOs.  It has a bootup sequence that I must follow - first turn on the 5v regulator (a separate device), then power on the peripheral, finally release reset after at least 5 ms have passed.  So I have 3 GPIOs, 5v_en, power_on and reset_n.  The peripheral takes about a minute to get from power-on to operational, so there cannot be unnecessary reboots.  Other requirements are that I toggle reset to complete firmware/config updates and I have a low-power mode where the peripheral and regulator are off.

There are three options I see, and none of them are ideal.

For these examples, assume gpio0=5v_en, gpio1=power_on and gpio2=reset_n

---

Option #1: Sysfs (deprecated)

```
cd /sys/class/gpio
echo 0 > export
echo 1 > export
echo 2 > export
echo out > gpio0/direction
echo out > gpio1/direction
echo out > gpio2/direction
echo 1 > gpio0/value
echo 1 > gpio1/value
sleep 1
echo 1 > gpio2/value
```

Have the above in an init script.  When I need to change the value of a pin, simply `open` the value file and write in the new value.  This makes the most sense to me.  Unfortunately, it is now deprecated.

---

Option #2: `gpioset`

```
gpioset -m signal -b 1 0=1
gpioset -m signal -b 1 1=1
sleep 1
gpioset -m signal -b 1 2=1
```

Have the above in an init script.  When I need to change the value of a pin, determine the PID of the `gpioset` process, `kill` the process and relaunch with the new value.  While gpioset is not running, the state of the pin is technically "undefined."  Doesn't seem like the way to go.

---

Option #3: Daemon

Instead of running gpioset, write my own custom daemon with the sole purpose of keeping an open file descriptor to the gpio character devices in /dev.  The program must be simple and minimal because if it crashes, the state of all GPIOs it is managing becomes undefined.  However it must also maintain some kind of IPC to talk to other programs that want to control the GPIOs.  Essentially, we've slapped a layer of indirection in to keep things that want to use the GPIOs from using them directly.

This feels drastically over-engineered, and drafting, implementing, and documenting the IPC protocol is really annoying compared to letting everybody use /sys/gpio as they like.

---

I have a feeling that Option #3 is how Linux intends us to manage GPIOs going forward, but it slaps on a lot of extra work for no benefit in this particular use case.
With this question, I hope to understand

1. Are there any other strategies I haven't considered that would make more sense?
2. How can I mitigate the risk of a crashed program leading to undefined GPIO states?